filter an array of objects in swift says trailiing closure passed... that does not accept a closure
I have, what I thought was a simple problem, filter an array of objects, but for whatever reason Xcode has decided that filter does not allow a trailing closure. I have been banging my head against a wall for like an hour trying to figure out why I can't filter an array of objects. Here's a the code I am working with, hopefully this is just something stupid I am missing.
public struct MultiLineChartData: Identifiable {
    public let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    public var title: String
    public var data: [(day: Date, amount: Int)]
    public var formattedValue: String
    
    public init(title: String, data: [(day: Date, amount: Int)], formattedValue: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.data = data
        self.formattedValue = formattedValue
    }
}

So then I create an array of MultiLineChartData and attempt to filter it by a specific date...
static func getEntriesFromSelection(_ data: [MultiLineChartData], selectedDay: Date) -> [MultiLineChartData] {
  let searchDay = dateSearchFormat.string(from: selectedDay)
  return data.filter {
    return dateSearchFormat.string(from: $0.data.day) == searchDay
  }
}

However, right there at return data.filter { Xcode is giving me an error...

Trailing closure passed to parameter of type
'Predicate' that does not accept a closure

Everything I have found online, and other code I have written all work just fine as a filter, but I can't figure out why this specific instance is telling me that filter doesn't accept a closure.

The problem is the phrase $0.data.day. $0.data is MultiLineChartData's data, which is an array of tuples. An array has no day.

You have two data, one in the func getEntriesFromSelection(_ data: [MultiLineChartData],..., which is an array of [MultiLineChartData].
The other is in each element of that array, that is, var data: [(day: Date, amount: Int)].
This is another array of tuples, and an array does not have the
value .day as you have in $0.data.day.
Depending on what you want to filter, try this approach
 func getEntriesFromSelection(_ data: [MultiLineChartData], selectedDay: Date) -> [MultiLineChartData] {
     let searchDay = dateSearchFormat.string(from: selectedDay)
     return data.filter {
         if let first = $0.data.first {
             return dateSearchFormat.string(from: first.day) == searchDay
         } else {
             return false
         }
     }
 }


did my answer not worked for you?
